# Get count of a character within string

Tags: vb.net, string

How do you count specific character occurrences in a string in VB.NET?
Like for example I have a string of:

> 123#17453#40110#065

I would like to determine what is the code of getting the count of `#` sign
which is `3`.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a lambda expression:

```
 Dim s As String = "123#17453#40110#065"
 Dim result = s.Where(Function(c) c = "#"c).Count
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim count = "123.0#17453#40110#065".Count(Function(x) x = "#")
```

Or via an extension method placed in a module:

```
<Extension> Public Function Occurs(target As String, character As Char) As Integer
    Return target.Count(Function(c) c = character)
End Function

Dim count = "123.0#17453#40110#065".Occurs("#"c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Verbose VB.NET example:

```
Dim s As String = "123#17453#40110#065"
Dim count As Integer = 0
For Each c As Char In s
    If c = "#" Then count = count + 1
Next
Console.WriteLine("'#' appears {0} times.", count)
```

Obligatory minimalistic C# example:

```
Int32 count = "123#17453#40110#065".Count( c => c == '#' );
```